# Read csv file separated by semicolons (";") using the {arrow} package in R

Tags: r, csv, apache-arrow

I have a semicolon-separated csv file that has millions of rows of data. I want to use `arrow` to read it faster, but arrow doesn't provide a function like `readr::read_csv2` or `read.csv2` in base. How can I read a semicolon-separated csv file using arrow's implementation for R?

Comment: `arrow::read_delim_arrow("your/path", delim = ";")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read a csv file that's separated by semicolons using the arrow package, use the argument `parse_options = CsvParseOptions$create(delimiter = ";")` inside your reading function, like this:

```
library(arrow)
data <- arrow::read_csv_arrow("data/AtencionesUrgencia2022.csv",
                                    parse_options = CsvParseOptions$create(delimiter = ";"))
```